# inserting two column image in desired place

Tags: graphics, floats, double-sided

I am creating an IJCA article.I have a situation where I have to insert a two column image at some place.After that normal text follow.I used the package **float**.I am attaching the code below.

```
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{result}
\caption{result of process}
\label{fig:result}
\end{figure*}
```

But now the image is displayed in the next page center rather than the position where I wanted.How to make it display it where I wanted??

Comment: Normally, a `figure*` can only appear at the top of a page, don't think you can do anything about that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think this is unclear: there is no MWE and we don't even know where the desired place is. (Is the problem just that it is on the next page rather than this one? Or is it also that it is at the wrong place on the page it is on?)

Comment: This is a very commonly asked question and more can be found on duplicate of [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)